# Give access to SharePoint site to another tenant using B2B direct connect

Tags: sharepoint-online

I've added another tenant in my azure AD under `External Identities | Cross-tenant access settings`

How do I give access to this tenant of my SharePoint site so that they can see it while logging into their SharePoint?

Answer (score 0):

To give access to your SharePoint site to users from another tenant, you can follow these steps:

1, Follow [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/turn-external-sharing-on-or-off) to complete the external sharing setup.

2, Go to the SharePoint site that you want to share.

3, settings-->site permissions-->advanced permissions settings, go to site permission panel. Grant permissions--> invite people and then enter the email address of the user from the other tenant that you want to share the site with.

4, Choose the appropriate permission level for the user (e.g. read-only, edit, etc.).

5, Click "Share" to send the invitation.

The user from the other tenant will receive an email invitation to access the SharePoint site. They will need to log in with their own credentials to access the site.